# Notion of `normal bundle' of a submanifold in a Finsler manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, finsler-geometry

Given a submanifold $N$ in a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$, we have the notion of normal bundle $$\nu(N) := \{(p,v) \in TM \; | \; p \in N, \, g(v, w) = 0 \, \forall w \in T_p N\}.$$ It is well-known that a distance minimimizing geodesic from $N$ has to start in the normal bundle. That is, if $\gamma :[0,1] \to M$ is a unit speed geodesic satisfying $\gamma(0) \in N$ and $\text{dist}(N, \gamma(t)) = t$ for some time $t \in [0,t_0] \subset[0,1]$, then $\dot\gamma(0) \in \nu(N)|_{\gamma(0)}$. Here $\text{dist}(\_,\_)$ is the induced distance.

Now, suppose we have a Finsler manifold $(M,F)$ and a submanifold $N \subset M$. Is there any notion of 'normal bundle' of $N$ here, so that the initial velocity of any distance minimizing geodesic from $N$ must lie in this normal bundle?

Any references or comments regarding this will be highly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: There is a natural definition of the normal bundle in terms of the Finsler metric, and the initial velocity of any distance minimizing geodesic from the submanifold must lie in this normal bundle.

Comment: If you want to use minimizing geodesics, it is likely that you need smoothness of norms in tangent spaces.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am going by the usual convention of assuming $F : TM \to [0, \infty)$ to be continuous, and to be smooth outside the $0$-section. Isn't this enough to consider minimizing geodesic from a submanifold?

Comment: Just consider the $l_1$-metric on the plane and observe nonuniqueness of minimizing geodesics...

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't see why uniqueness is an issue here! I am not asking for unique minimizing geodesic.

Comment: So, it does not bother you that if $M\subset R^2$ is the $x$-axis, then the space of tangent directions to minimizing (to $M$) geodesics starting at $p=(0,0)$ is not a linear subspace of the tangent plane at $p$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think this is what my question is about. In your example, let $\nu_p \subset T_p \mathbb{R}^2$ be the collection of all directions at $p \in M \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, along which we get minimizing (to $M$) geodesics. If $\nu_p$ is not a linear subspace, then what other properties can we expect? Can we characterize $\nu_p$ in any other way?